# In GBoard, how can I set multilingual input for English and Swiss German?

Tags: languages, gboard

The majority of my phone useage happens in either English or Swiss German, and I switch between these languages frequently, even within the same conversation. In GBoard settings, I see the following multilingual options:

- In the English keyboard settings: German
- In the German keyboard settings: English
- In the Swiss German keyboard settings: German

None of these allow me to have English+Swiss German multilingual support. Is there a way this can be achieved?

Comment: If you have installed multiple languages in GBoard you can switch between them by pressing and holding space. https://support.google.com/gboard/answer/7068494?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

Comment: I’m aware of this, but it’s inconvenient to do repeatedly in the middle of a conversation. I code-switch a lot when chatting, language may change multiple times within a single message. Note that I have additional layouts installed — Japanese, Japanese Handwriting and IPA — rendering the button that cycles through layouts virtually useless as well. I would find it acceptable if I could set defaults for which layout to switch to when pressing that button, but I don’t think that’s possible either.

Comment: I have just now discovered that the language switch key actually switches back to the previous language you had set if you’ve typed something. Thus I _can_ use that to switch back and forth regardless of other installed layouts. This may be good enough. Still, if there’s a way to just have multilingual setup that would be far nicer.